# How to update hash by adding keys from the list in perl

Tags: list, perl, hash

Adding a set of keys when declaring a hash is straightforward as -

```
my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @list;
```

If I want to add more keys from another list, how can I achieve that with single line?

Comment: You can also do: `my %h = map {$_ => 1} @list, 99, 107, @list2, @list3;`. Essentially, `map` takes a list, and what that does is squish all of your items into a larger list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `%hash`  declared you may use `@hash{LIST}`, with existing or new keys in `LIST`

```
@hash{ @more_keys } = @values_for_new_keys;
```

See [Slices in perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)

---

If you meant to initiliaze the new keys to a fixed value, you can do for example

```
@hash { @more_keys } = (1) x @more_keys;
```

where `(1) x N` returns a list of `1`s of length `N`, and `@more_keys` in scalar context returns its length.

Comment: I wanted to initialize new keys to a fixed value. I did the following and it worked - `@hash{ @more_keys } = 1`

Comment: @vp8  Does `@more_keys` have more than one element? That assigns a single value to a list and so it should only assign to the first element of the list and truncate the rest.

Comment: @zdim not truncated, just assigns undef as the value for all the added keys but the first

Comment: @ysth  Yes, thank you -- I meant that for an existing list in general, when assigned a single value it ends up with just one element with that value.  But here all keys _are_ added so the others stay (and `undef`).  Thank you for correction

Comment: @zdim you are right! I ended up having `undef` for other keys. Thanks @zdim and @ysth !

Comment: @vp8 Good that you mentioned it!  It saves a bug in the future, when there are more than one key being added. (To correct a slip-up in my comment regarding a general case: a value can be assigned to _an array_, not to a "list" as I wrote. It's more complicated in the situtation at hand with a hash, but my first comment on that was about truncating an independent array to one element.)